# problem with request.post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller that has the following index action :

```
def index
  if request.post?
    flash[:notice] = "Searching.."
    redirect_to songs_path # where songs_path is this index page that i am on 
  end
end
```

in my application layout i have defined the flash section as such

> ```
> <% if flash[:notice] %>
>   <div id='notice'><%= flash[:notice] %></div>
> <% end %>
> ```

and on my pages_path i've got

```
<% form_for :search do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :search_text %>
  <%= f.text_field :search_text %>
  <p>
    <%= f.submit "Search" %>
  </p>
<% end %>
```

The final result should be a search through a youtube api ( youtube-g) but now i would only wish to make that flash notification appear when i click on the "Search" button , and it doesn't .. any ideas why ?

Comment: `redirect_to songs_path` - isn't it redirection loop? very bad one :)

Comment: i've commented the redirection and it still doesn't work :-??

Comment: what route have you for form_for :search do |f| ?

Comment: you should read about REST :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

index action ordinary is GET request. So, if in your routes.rb there is something like `resources :searches` then your code won't work.

try this:

```
def create
  render :text => "Searching.."
end
```

because POST /searches will refer to create action

Answer (score 0):

you should update your RESTful route to like this

```
resources :songs do 
    collection do 
        get 'search'
    end
end
```

Then in your Controller

```
def search
    # Perform Your search here like Youtube ..
    flash[:notice] = "Searching.."
    redirect_to songs_path # This should work now.
end
```